# Roomba schedule opcode: 167, byte 1

Tags: irobot-create

Just a short question: The iRobot Create 2 Open Interface spec says:

Serial sequence: [167] [Days] [Sun Hour] [Sun Minute] [Mon Hour] etc.

Can somebody explain to me, what "Days" stands for?

Comment: Can you provide more information? What is this? A vacuum cleaner, industrial welder, PLC? Manufacturer, model number? Can you link to a manual?

Comment: This looks like Roomba programming.  I know the days byte is an 8-bit character where each bit represents a day of the week (high bit reserved).  There are many Roomba programming sites available and suggest you look there - I am sure there are detailed instructions because of the way they allowed that interface to be open.

Comment: Here is one:  http://www.joshbillions.org/post/410626127/add-scheduling-to-a-roomba-532-via-arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course, it is a roomba create 2. sorry for this..

The last comment helped: the requested variable stands for: the sum of days of a week, the roomba is meant to work.

Value Day: 1 Sunday, 2 Monday, 4 Tuesday, 8 Wednesday, 16 Thursday, 32 Friday, 64 Saturday

Examples: 127 = every day, 40 = Wednesday and Friday

Thank you! :)